# PHP creating xml

Tags: php, xml, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to make an xml export thing. Everything is okay but I have a problem, I need to make a special xml tag. I'm trying to export like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product id="13849">
        <name>product name</name>
    </product>
</products>
```

but my export looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product id=13849>
        <name>product name</name>
    </product id=13849>
</products >
```

My code is:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><xml/>');
        $rows = (new Product)->getProducts(1, 0, 0, 'id_product', 'ASC', 18, true);
$start = $xml->addChild("products");
foreach($rows AS $row)
        {   
            $xml_sub = $start->addChild("product id=".$row["id_product"]."");
            $product = new Product($row["id_product"]);
            $xml_sub->addChild("name", $row['name']);   
                }
```

About `addChild("product id=".$row["id_product"]."");` I need to make a change but I can't find an example to help me :(

Thank you

Comment: try `$start->addChild("product id=". strval($row["id_product"]) ."");` - i suspect you had to explicitly add double quotes. is so, this `$start->addChild("product id="."$row['id_product']"."")` should do.

Comment: @Tezla again same problem making that </product id=13849> i need to close it that like this </product>

Comment: well, sorry, perhaps this work `$xml_sub = $start->addChild("product")->addAttribute("id", "$row['id_product']")`, [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php) - sorry wrong function.

Comment: @Tezla if you add your comment like a answer i will accept that because maybe one day someone need that information :)